# Oracle trigger to indicate a single cell to be updated

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I created a simple table named test1 like below:

[image]

I am going to update END_SESSION column where You can see null value, so the update statement should be like this:
***UPDATE test1 SET end_session = 3500 where end_session is null***

However the idea is to avoid ***where*** condition in UPDATE statement and create trigger to indicate which cell should be updated (must be null). I created a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger updateEND_SESSION
before update of end_session on test1
for each row
declare
    lastROW number;
begin
    select max(NUMER_ID) into lastROW
    from TEST1;
    UPDATE TEST1
    SET END_SESSION = :NEW.END_SESSION
    WHERE NUMER_ID = lastROW;
end;
```

but I can see the following error:
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'MMDMANAGER.UPDATEENDSESSION' is invalid and failed re-validation

Can anybody know how to create such a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad idea. You would write an update for all rows and the trigger would saveguard any already existing values from getting overwritten. That's a lot of work for the DBMS, because all rows get updated, only most of them with the value they already have.

This would be the code:

```
create or replace trigger trg_update_end_session
before update of end_session on test1
for each row
begin
  if :old.end_session is not null then
    :new.end_session := old.end_session;
  end if;
end;
```

The statement

```
update test1 set end_session = 3500;
```

would then only set end_session to 3500 where it was null before.

Comment: Ok, actually it works however all records from the table have been updated. What do You think about declaring CURSOR and indicate that only the row where the third column is null can be updated?

Comment: Such a trigger fires for every row and performs some action. If you only want an action on a single row, then a trigger is to late. Something must be done before. Usually by providing a where clause as in your original example. Is your only concern really not to want to write that small where clause? Or are you worried existing values ma get changed mistakenly by an inappropriate update statement? I've just provided another answer covering this.

Comment: This is why triggers should be regulated to very advanced database topics. Not because they are hard, but because they are vastly misused. The net result of this trigger would be a rewrite the entire table, even if no data value is changed; including UNDO tablespace (rollback 10g or less), row locks on each row, etc. And why are you trying to avoid the most basic clause for controlling what gets processed.  Maybe not so bad with a 3row or 300row table but how about 300M rows.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to write a trigger to prevent changes of already existing values:

```
create or replace trigger trg_update_end_session
before update of end_session on test1
for each row
begin
  if :new.end_session <> :old.end_session then
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'end_session must not be changed');
  end if;
end;
```

Then

```
update test1 set end_session = 3500;
```

would fail. You would have to write

```
update test1 set end_session = 3500 where end_session is null;
```

or provide a stored procededure

```
create or replace procedure update_end_session(v_value integer) as
begin
  update test1 set end_session = v_value where end_session is null;
end;
```